# How to format python interpreter text?

Tags: python

I am trying to edit the text that pops up when I launch the python3 interpret.
This should be a very simple task and I am trying to use the PYTHONSTARTUP environment variable set to a file .pythonrc.py but I am not 100% sure what I am doing. For some reason I cannot find a simple script that shows how this is done.
I do not have my own generated code because I didn't even write the code for my terminal customization. I just googled how to edit, found some examples and then tweeked it from there.

I just want to know how to change this.

```
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 03:03:55) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: That information comes from the Python build.

Comment: right. is there not a way to remove it? or maybe change it to say something?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ python -i -c "print('my own banner')"
my own banner
>>>
```

Comment: Ok, that did work but thats not what im trying to accomplish. I would like to just type $ python3 and then 'My own banner" or whatever will come up and not the version info and stuff

Comment: So just make an alias in your .bashrc.  I have this one, personally: `alias py='python -i -c ""'`.

Comment: i added export PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/.pythonrc.py to my .bash_profile( i have a mac). I just found this doing research and then the pythonrc.py will contain the script that edits the info.

Comment: i dont know. I assumed it was just as easy as changing the terminal info, but apparently its not. I can swear I saw a youtube video and guy launched his python3 and it was just the '>>>' that started. I could be wrong.

Comment: And how do you know he doesn't alias python3 to that?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. I tried adding the alias line to my bash_profile. And I already had an alias line for my terminal edit. The alias made no change to my python3

Comment: 1.  `alias python3='python3 -q'`   2. `python3`

Comment: Thank you!!!! I will use this and learn from it. I really appreciate it!